# xdebug Процесс адаптера отладки неожиданно

Tags: php, visual-studio-code, xdebug

Установил Visual Studio Code и пытаюсь дебажить страницу с php скриптами. Но ничего не получается. Я использую NGINX в качестве сервера.
Вот мои настройки php.ini:

```
extension=php_phalcon.dll
;extension=php_xdebug-2.5.1-7.0-vc14-nts-x86_64.dll
zend_extension=php_xdebug-2.5.1-7.0-vc14-nts-x86_64.dll

[XDebug]
xdebug.remote_enable = 1
xdebug.remote_autostart = 1
xdebug.remote_port = 9090
```

Вот ошибка:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Она вылазит каждый раз, когда я нажимаю F5. 
Вот мой файл настроек дебага:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0):

Смею предположить, у Вас nginx в связке с php-fpm. Настройки php-fpm скорее всего используют порт 9000, который в свою очередь Вы используете в настройках XDebug и VS Code.

**Решение:**

В VS Code установить ***port: 9500***

В php.ini добавить в раздел [XDebug] ***xdebug.remote_port = 9500***